# Supporting WebGL1 + WebGL2

Tags: webgl, webgl2, webgl-extensions

I have a certain library that uses WebGL1 to render things.
It heavily uses float textures and instanced rendering.

Nowadays it seems like support for WebGL1 is pretty weird, with some devices supporting for example WebGL2, where these extensions are core, but not supporting WebGL1, or supporting it, but not the extensions.

At the same time, support for WebGL2 isn't amazing. Maybe one day it will be, but for not it isn't.

I started looking at what it will take to support both versions.

For shaders, I think I can mostly get away with `#define`ing things. For example, `#define texture2D texture` and other similar things.

When it comes to extensions, it becomes more problematic, since the extension objects no longer exist.
As an experiment, I tried copying the extension properties into the context object, e.g. `gl.drawArraysInstanced = (...args) => ext.drawArraysInstancedANGLE(...args)`.

When it comes to textures, not much needs to be changed, perhaps add something like `gl.RGBA8 = gl.RGBA` when running in WebGL1, thus it will "just work" when running in WebGL2.

So then comes the question...did anyone try this?
I am worried about it hurting performance, especially the extra indirection for function calls.
It will also make reading the code less obvious if the assumption is that it can run in WebGL1. After all, no WebGL1 context has `drawArraysInstanced`, or `RGBA8`. This also bothers Typescript typing and other minor things.

The other option is to have branches all over the code. Two versions of shaders (or `#ifdef` trickery), lots of brancing for every place where texture formats are needed, and every place where instancing is done.
Having something like what follows all over the place is pretty ugly:

```
if (version === 1) {
  instancedArrays.vertexAttribDivisorANGLE(m0, 1);
  instancedArrays.vertexAttribDivisorANGLE(m1, 1);
  instancedArrays.vertexAttribDivisorANGLE(m2, 1);
  instancedArrays.vertexAttribDivisorANGLE(m3, 1);
} else {
  gl.vertexAttribDivisor(m0, 1);
  gl.vertexAttribDivisor(m1, 1);
  gl.vertexAttribDivisor(m2, 1);
  gl.vertexAttribDivisor(m3, 1);
}
```

Finally, maybe there's a third way I didn't think about.

Got any recommendations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately I think most answers will be primarily opinion based.

The first question is why support both? If your idea runs fine on WebGL1 then just use WebGL1. If you absolutely must have WebGL2 features then use WebGL2 and realize that many devices don't support WebGL2.

If you're intent on doing it [twgl](https://twgljs.org) tries to make it easier by [providing a function that copies all the WebGL1 extensions into their WebGL2 API positions](http://twgljs.org/docs/module-twgl.html#.addExtensionsToContext). For like you mentioned, instead of

```
ext = gl.getExtension('ANGLE_instanced_arrays');
ext.drawArraysInstancedANGLE(...)
```

You instead do

```
twgl.addExtensionsToContext(gl);
gl.drawArraysInstanced(...);
```

I don't believe there will be any noticeable perf difference. Especially since those functions are only called a few hundred times a frame the wrapping is not going to be the bottleneck in your code.

The point though is not really to support WebGL1 and WebGL2 at the same time. Rather it's just to make it so the way you write code is the same for both APIs.

Still, there are real differences in the 2 APIs. For example to use a FLOAT RGBA texture in WebGL1 you use

```
gl.texImage2D(target, level, gl.RGBA, width, height, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.FLOAT, ...)
```

In WebGL2 it's

```
gl.texImage2D(target, level, gl.RGBA32F, width, height, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.FLOAT, ...)
```

WebGL2 will fail if you try to call it the same as WebGL1 in this case. [There are other differences](https://webgl2fundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl1-to-webgl2.html) as well.

Will work just fine in WebGL1 and WebGL2. The spec specifically says that combination results in RGBA8 on WebGL2.

Note though that your example of needing RGBA8 is not true.

```
gl.texImage2D(target, level, gl.RGBA, width, height, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, ...)
```

The biggest difference though is there is no reason to use WebGL2 if you can get by with WebGL1. Or, visa versa, if you need WebGL2 then you probably can not easily fall back to WebGL1

For example you mentioned using defines for shaders but what are you going to do about features in WebGL2 that aren't in WebGL1. Features like `textureFetch` or the mod `%` operator, or integer attributes, etc.... If you need those features you mostly need to write a WebGL2 only shader. If you don't need those features then there was really no point in using WebGL2 in the first place.

Of course if you really want to go for it maybe you want to make a fancier renderer if the user has WebGL2 and fall back to a simpler one if WebGL1.

TD;LR IMO Pick one or the other

Comment: To be more precise - I don't mean actually using WebGL2-specific features. If support for it was bigger sure, but right now it seems to hover around 50%, which is abysmal. Rather I want my current code to run on WebGL2. Normally this wouldn't make much sense, however like I said, I have encountered reports from users stating weird things like having WebGL2 support and not WebGL1 support. This is merely to support such devices, nothing more. While I am not interested in WebGL helper code, I will check the way twgl injects the extensions, maybe they have nicer code than mine

Comment: About perf - it's sort of true that this shouldn't be my worry, the usage of functions like setting instanced attributes is generally <0.3% of my code, while most of the time is spent on client stuff like updating node hierarchies. Maybe I am being too pedantic.

Comment: Just as a side comment, WebGL2 actually rejected my existing texImage2D calls using RGBA, but I also didn't really look into it. Either way it could be "supported" by e.g. defining RGBA8=RGBA and RGBA32F=RGBA for a WebGL1 context

Comment: There should not be any configurations that support WebGL2 but not WebGL1. File a bug whenever you see this.

The exception to this is some extensions which aren't supportable in WebGL1, but are available on WebGL2 on the same systems, such as draw_buffers and shader_texture_lod.

Comment: In such a case the code will indeed not work. For example I do also use shader_texture_lod, so in such an implementation, running on WebGL2 would be the only solution on my end. A person reported on github about having a WebGL2 context but not a WebGL1 one. Go figure

Answer (score 0):

I found this question when writing a documentation of my library, which has many objectives, but one of them is exactly this - to support WebGL1 and WebGL2 in the same time for higher cross-device compatibility.

https://xemantic.github.io/shader-web-background/

For example I discovered with [BrowserStack](https://www.browserstack.com/) that Samsung phones don't support rendering to floating point textures in WebGL1, while it is perfectly fine for them in WebGL2. In the same time WebGL2 will never appear on Apple devices, but rendering to half floating point textures is pretty well supported.

My library is not providing full WebGL abstraction, but rather will configure pipeline for fragment shaders. Here is the source on GitHub with the WebGL strategy code depending on the version:

https://github.com/xemantic/shader-web-background/blob/main/src/main/js/webgl-utils.js

Therefore to answer your question, it is doable and desirable, but doing it in a totally generic way, for every WebGL feature, might be quite challenging. I guess the first question to ask is "What would be the common denominator?" in terms of supported extensions.

Comment: as of 11/1/2022, WebGL2 works on Safari/Mac and Safari/iOS